# Resolve gradle dependencies for published libraries

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a package `package A` that has been published and another published package `package B`. B has a dependency on A. There a testing app in the project folder for A. At this point the updated version for A is not published. I can't make an update to A and have the test app compile with package B as dependency. The compiler throws duplicate class p

build.gradle for testing application.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'package-B'
    implementation project(":A")

}
```